# is this to many if statements? or can this be optimized better?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am in the very early stages of the Learn.unity tutorial series. I am trying to write a script to move an object back and forth in front of a window. I feel like I have way to many if statements in here I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveBucket : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 bucketMove;
    Vector3 startPosition;
    public float resetPosition;
    public bool sendBack;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        startPosition = transform.localPosition;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (transform.localPosition.x <= resetPosition)
        {
            sendBack = true;
        }
        if (transform.localPosition.x >= startPosition.x)
        {
            sendBack = false;
        }
        if (sendBack == true)
        {
            transform.localPosition -= bucketMove;
        }
        else if (sendBack == false)
        {
            transform.localPosition += bucketMove;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it works you should post on Code Review instead. But there's probably too little context here anyway. What if neither of the first two `if` conditions are met - what will `sendBack` be then?

Comment: The last if/then/else can be reduced to `if (sendback) { /* code */ } else { /* other code */ }`. Booleans only have two states

Comment: Some of this is going to be opinion. You are setting the boolean value of a single property, `sendBack`, to either true or false. You should be able to create a single query to set that value. The 2 queries you have there look a bit contradictory as well, so think about the best way to word it. Is it `true` unless this one specific condition is hit? Then set the default value to true and change if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it shorter, but I think it only makes it less readable.

```
sendBack = transform.localPosition.x <= resetPosition && !(transform.localPosition.x >= startPosition.x)

transform.localPosition += (bucketMove * (sendBack ? 1 : -1 ))
```

Comment: actually instead of `!(transform.localPosition.x >= startPosition.x)` you can just do `transform.localPosition.x < startPosition.x` to improve readability ;)

Comment: That's true, I choose the negative form to make it more "understandable" when compared to the old version for the sake of the answer, but yes, it's more readable in the positive form :)